# How do I set IP access / password restrictions in Apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, passenger, restriction

I'd like to restrict access to my Rails app (running on Apache/Passenger) to just two IPs, but if the visitor doesn't fall into those two IPs, I would like for him/her to be prompted to enter a password that would allow any user with the proper credentials to access the site from anywhere.

I am new to configuring Apache and would appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with .htaccess files, something like:

```
AuthName "Lee's Secret Area"
AuthType Basic 
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 199.166.210.
allow from .golden.net
allow from proxy.aol.com
allow from fish.wiretap.net
</Limit>
```

for instance